# Differentiate between clicking rows and clicking checboxes in Mui Data Grid

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, datagrid

Like the title says - is there a way to differeniate between clicking basically a row and clicking the checkboxes?

[image]

I'd would like to be able to select multiple rows but upon clicking in a row - so anywhere other than in the checkbox column - I want to do something else, like call a react hook (open a modal) etc.

Currently I am able to select only by clicking the checkboxes but if I add back `onCellClick` to open a modal when clicking a row, it also works for the checkbox. So basically I don't want to call `onCellClick` for the checkbox column ONLY, but for every other column I do.

[image]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `onCellClick` you can use `data.field` to see whether or not it is a click of the checkbox column, and if so then ignore that click. Below is a working example.

```
import * as React from "react";
import { DataGrid } from "@mui/x-data-grid";
import { useDemoData } from "@mui/x-data-grid-generator";

export default function DisableClickSelectionGrid() {
  const { data } = useDemoData({
    dataSet: "Commodity",
    rowLength: 10,
    maxColumns: 6
  });

  return (
    <div style={{ height: 400, width: "100%" }}>
      <DataGrid
        checkboxSelection
        disableRowSelectionOnClick
        {...data}
        onCellClick={(data) => {
          if (data.field === "__check__") {
            console.log("ignoring checkbox column");
          } else {
            console.log("Do your main logic here", data);
          }
        }}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit onCellClick]